# How to fix the width and height of div and make the content inside div resize to div's width and height?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div with an ID. I am changing the div html using jquery.

The html may have iframe with large width and height. I want to have the div with fixed width and height. and the content of the iframe should resize to the divs width and height.

Help.

This is what i tried so far but its not working.

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script>
var html =  // get it from somewhere e.g. <iframe width=300px height=500px ></iframe> 

jQuery("#myDiv").attr("max-width","200px");
jQuery("#myDiv").attr("max-height","300px");

jQuery("#myDiv").html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of the iframe is generally unaware of it's "parent" container, thus the sizing of it's contents aren't guaranteed. If you want your iframe's content to be resized...this can only be accomplished through javascript if it's in the same domain. Or if its a different domain, the url would require parameters/logic and resize the content through javascript based on those  parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "css" function. not the attr or prop function. because the max-* properties that you are trying to add are css prop.

```
jQuery("#myDiv").css("max-width","200px");
jQuery("#myDiv").css("max-height","300px");
```

Comment: basically what I am trying to do is to add embed code from youtube to my app in a div. But since my div will have fixed width and height, it will be a problem. How do i solve this?